# Is there a performance difference between computed properties vs functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, performance, caching, computed-values

Lets say you have a SwiftUI view that has lots of expensive computed vars that call each-other on the main thread "spaghetti style" with state variables as the source of truth, such as:

// This is extremely simplified for basic illustration.  These are much more numerous and expensive operations in real app with a complex web of dependencies where calling one could result in another being called several times.

```
@State var a:Double
@State var b:Double
@State var c:Double

var aTimesB:Double {
    return a * b
}

var bTimesC:Double {
    return b * c
}

var computation1:Double {
    return doSuperExpensiveThingWith(aTimesB + bTimesC)
}
```

Is it true that the result of computed vars like this are not cached at runtime (and therefore will be re-run even if not necessary, (for example, if we were to change value c, aTimesB would still re-compute anyway)) but if I were to change them into functions that take arguments instead of making spaghetti calls... like this:

```
@State var a:Double
@State var b:Double
@State var c:Double

func aTimesB(a:Double, b:Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}

func bTimesC(b:Double, c:Double) -> Double {
    return b * c
}

func computation1(item1:Double, item2:Double) -> Double {
    return doSuperExpensiveThisWith(item1 + item2)
}
```

... that they would be cached (in the event that the arguments sent to them were found to be the same as the previous call), thus increasing performance?

Comment: A function doesn't get cached. What makes you think it would be cached?

Comment: I don't know... I heard it somewhere... and it would make sense to cache the result of a function if the arguemtns sent to it are identical to the previous call (and its body doesn't involve dynamic... stuff) but I just did a A/B test in the "real project" and the answer seems to be a resounding YES.  I just don't know how to explain why or how to verify it in Instruments.

Comment: The only way it would be cached is if you put the result somewhere like a State. If you use a function like you use a computed property I don’t think it would make a difference it would still run every time the body reloads. But you can “cache” a computed variable too if you put its value in a State.

Comment: @NerdyBunz substituting function calls with precomputed result values is possible, but totally not done by default. The equality checking and hashing needing to look up a value from a hash table will take way longer than a simple function body like your example. It’s also only possible when the function is proved to be “pure” (not have any “side effects”).

Comment: Computed properties are not cached. Lazy variables are cached. Computed properties are evaluated every time you reference them.

Comment: Function results are not cached either. It would be a very big lift for the compiler to generate code that determined that the inputs (and instance variables, and global state) had not changed, and that the function did not have any side-effects, so that it could skip its code and return the same value as last time.

Comment: Your intro into your actual problem suggests, that you should not compute the state within SwiftUI. Instead, perform the computation external (within a "Model", "ViewModel" or "Store" or a Finite State Machine). That external computation then provides your state which the view renders. Using a FSA, you can also avoid the spaghetti code you have been talked and your logic becomes a simple, pure function without undesired dependencies ;)

Answer (score 0):

A computed property is "syntactic sugar", which is to say it's a language feature that does the same thing as something else, but in a way that reads better. Quoting the [Wiki article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar):

> syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. It makes the language "sweeter" for human use: things can be expressed more clearly, more concisely, or in an alternative style that some may prefer. Syntactic sugar is usually a shorthand for a common operation that could also be expressed in an alternate, more verbose, form"

A computed property **is** a function (or more accurately, a closure. But a closure is an anonymous function.) A computed property is a way of calling a closure that takes no parameters and returns a value. It makes it look to the reader as if the thing is a variable/property, but it's really code that gets evaluated.

I'd have to look at the generated assembler to be certain, but I'm willing to bet that with optimization turned on, there would be no difference in the compiler output between the two.